# Integrate the dropbox in my application which show security alert

Tags: android, dropbox

I have developed one application successfully I want to store the database in drop box. So I am using dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.4 example which is working fine to me.

My problem is when I integrate this sdk example application in my application and make a login process at that time it show one error:

> **"Another app on your phone may be trying to pose as the app you are currently using. The malicious app cannot access your account, but linking to Dropbox has been disabled as a precaution. Please contact support@dropbox.com."**

[image]

Comment: I am also trying the same but i am doing it on emulator,and got the same security dialog box, to get rid of it just what i did is started the emulator again by clearing the user data of emulator

Comment: how to clear user data

Comment: when you go to launcher select emulator ->press start -> wipe user data(check box) click on the checkbox and then press Launch

Comment: I may be wrong but the phone maintains the session for of login ,the security dialog box opened because i tried to run two dropbox application with two different app key and secret key ,i think you may have tried running multiple demo app with different key in your phone

Comment: no dude when i run this application seperately it will be working.My problem is when i integrate this application in another application it show this type of error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just a guess, but I think this might happen if you tried to reuse the app key and secret from the sample app in your own app, rather than creating a new application via https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps/create and using that key and secret.

Comment: no smarx i am generate a new secret key for my application in drop box.which key only i am used.

Comment: Had this problem when I used my app key in sample app for testing. Made a new app key, still didn't work! Had to remove the token folder as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an old question but  there is another possibility that has just bitten me so for future users who may hit the same issue:

> If in the process of authenticating you run into an error message like
>   "Another app on your phone may be trying to pose as the app you are
>   currently using." it means more than one app installed on the phone
>   has a callback activity registered for a single app key. You can fix
>   this error by deleting one of the offending apps or by switching to a
>   new app key.

I hit this issue by having different versions (debug & release) of the same app installed.

[Source Link](http://www.androidcookers.com/2013/04/dropbox-api-get-your-files-in-your.html)

Comment: This one fixed it for me , had the Dropbox Sample installed as well, good call.

Answer (score 2):

I just examined the code for the SDK, and it happens because you have 2 apps that handle the same scheme for the callback URL that Dropbox login page uses.

So when the user logs in to Dropbox using the browser, after successful login, the browser will open `db-123456789://somepath` where `123456789` is a unique id for your Dropbox app. If you have multiple apps installed on the device that handles the `db-123456789` URL scheme, you will end up receiving that warning.

I imagine that a malicious app could capture the access token when the browser gives it using the `db-123456789` scheme by handling that scheme specifically, hence the warning.

Answer (score 1):

It because more then one app use the same appKey. 
Check your apps for appKey - it must be unique for each app.
Delete all dropbox related apps from system apps list. In my case there was app with another applicationId and I did not see it on launch screen.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, when I was moving from different versions of the api. I had two instances of AuthActivity in the AndroidManifest.xml file, i.e.

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- <data android:scheme="db-c9buqx8hii5bxx8" /> -->

            <data android:scheme="xxxxxxxxxxx" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name="com.dropbox.core.android.AuthActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Insert your app key after “db-  ...” -->
            <data android:scheme="db-xxxxxxxxxx" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I found this after some debugging, and noticed that the dropbox library did a check for connection intent. If dropbox found more than one activity if would throw the security alert error. I duplicated the same check with the code below, and placed it in the main startup activity.  It will print out the activities found with the same dropbox intent, which gave me a clue on what was going on.

```
public static void showDropboxActivities(Context context)
{
    Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    String scheme = "db-" + DROPBOX_APP_KEY;
    String uri = scheme + "://" + com.dropbox.core.android.AuthActivity.AUTH_VERSION + "/connect";
    testIntent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, 0);

    Log.d("SomeApp", "------------- showDropboxActivities ------------");
    for (ResolveInfo activity : activities)
    {
        Log.d("SomeApp", "activty = " + activity.toString());
        Log.d("SomeApp", "activity.activityInfo = " + activity.activityInfo);
        Log.d("SomeApp","..............");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue recently and none of the answer solved this.

It started happening after trying the demo app and using the same app key for it. Came across this post but no luck.

Here is how I solved this:

1. Used a new app key: didn't work
2. Uninstall demo app with identical app key: didn't work
3. Removed token folder under my app's data directory: SOLVED!

EDIT: #3 can be replaced with clearing app's data after/before applying either #1 or #2.